# Sql if statement after another if check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with Microsoft SQL Server.

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ServerSettings'
        AND COLUMN_NAME = 'MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices'
)
    IF (
        SELECT MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices
        FROM ServerSettings
    ) = 0
        UPDATE ServerSettings
        SET MapCalculateDistanceSource = 0
```

Does anybody know why this code throw the error "Invalid column name". I thought that second select execute only when the first if is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the entire *batch* is first compiled, and then execution starts. Since it can't compile the batch because you reference an invalid column, it never executes the `if` statement.

You would need to protect the code that references a possibly absent column in an `EXEC`, something like:

```
if exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
          where TABLE_NAME = 'ServerSettings' and
                COLUMN_NAME = 'MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices')
begin
    exec('UPDATE ServerSettings SET MapCalculateDistanceSource = 0
          WHERE MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices = 0')
end
```

---

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sys.columns c 
    WHERE c.name = 'MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices'
        AND c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ServerSettings')
) BEGIN

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql '
        UPDATE dbo.ServerSettings
        SET MapCalculateDistanceSource = 0
        WHERE MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices = 0'

END
```

Comment: It still won't *compile*.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to check the existing column

```
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.ServerSettings', 'MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices') IS NOT NULL
EXEC ('UPDATE dbo.ServerSettings
       SET MapCalculateDistanceSource = 0
       WHERE MapIsAlwayCalcLenByWebServices = 0')
```

Comment: Your answer has the fastest execution plan, so I think this is the best answer among the others. And also my pleasure @Alexander Fedorenko :)